# Are Properties technically considered nonstatic in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, properties

My textbook is referring to the this reference and it first implies that a property is somewhat static and does not store one with each object, but one for the entire class. Then later it says that a property is nonstatic. I am really confused. What is it?

Comment: Unclear, can you elaborate with examples or specific text from the textbook?

Comment: It says: Instance methods and properties are nonstatic. We are referring to the class book with a property like: Title {get{return title;}}.

Comment: Why was this question closed as "not constructive"? That doesn't seem to fit here.

Comment: I have no idea why this would be not constructive. Voting to reopen. However, OP, please clarify exactly what this statement was from the book.

Answer (score 3):

- Properties can be static or not static.
- Static properties have the 'static' keyword, default is not static.
- Properties that are static are stored for the entire class (there is only one).
- Properties that are not static are stored per instance.

Answer (score 0):

A property can be both static and non-static you decide which by using the `static` keyword.

```
public static int StaticProperty {get; set; }
public int InstanceProperty {get; set; }
```

On a side note, a property is actually two methods (or just one if you only implement the `set` or `get`).

```
public int MyProperty {get; set; }
```

is equivalent to

```
public void set_MyProperty(int value);
public int get_MyProperty();
```